# Encoder in Digital Logic

Tags: logic, encoder, digital

[image]

I'd like to ask about how the truthtabel below is calculated, what I do not understand is how the output is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

The given encoder outputs the number of the *input* terminal (in binary) which is currently set to logical **HIGH**. There can be many logically equivalent ways to implement this internally. For example:

```
A0 = (not Y0 and Y1) or (not Y2 and Y3)
A1 = Y2 or Y3
```